# HTML: how to stop a html code in a string written in PHP from appearing as a Html Element on the Web Page

Tags: php, html

I am having problem in making html code in a string written PHP from appearing as an html element on the web page. What i really want is to make the html code to show as text on the page. Is there a way to preserve the html code in a string as string on the page?

Answer (score 4):

Use [htmlentities()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php).

It changes things like `<` and `>` to `&lt;` and `&gt;`.
Visually, they're exactly the same to the user but it won't be parsed as HTML tags.

Answer (score 0):

If you are displaying Html submitted by an end user, take it a step further and use http://htmlpurifier.org/ or http://tidy.sourceforge.net/ to remove potential submitted malicious code. For example, prevent some one from entering javascript, or php code, etc. That could in turn be used to cause trouble.